# I need help in removing fading boxes that appear when I click on input fields and other objects @ any website using CCleaner's Browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ccleaner

I've got an issue going on with my [CCleaner browser](https://www.ccleaner.com/) (built on Chrome). These silver-white borders appear over elements on web pages, and even the whole page itself, whenever I click on such an element. It only happens inside the CCleaner browser window, not in "regular" Chrome.

Here I would like to provide an example, taken from my edit account settings here on Stack Overflow dot com (a page you can look at that is exactly the same as mine except for my issue with my web browser).

[image: Display outline on field]

In that pic the border you see around the text entry box is what I get all the time. The box is not permanent; it slowly fades out and dissolves.

How do I prevent these silver borders from appearing in the first place?

Comment: For me it looks like a feature to mark the currently selected input field.

Answer (score 0):

**What it is**

It's something calles 'an outline' in CSS - and is something that can change from site to site. Do you see the same outline on all sites? If so, then it's something that CCleaner adds as a global styling, which sounds bonkers to me. I don't have any experience with CCleaner.

**Solution attempts**

1. Try and check out other sites, to see if they have the outline as well. If they don't then it's just the StackOverflow-site that has that styling.
2. Perhaps also try opening the site in an incognito-tab, to ensure that it's not another extension adding the styling.

Answer (score 0):

In Google chrome go to settings > Accessibility and untick (turn off)
Show a quick highlight on the focused object

and you done